# Adding HTML tags in Outlook add-in information message

Tags: outlook-web-addins

How can I show an html anchor tag in
    `Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync` method for "error" key? I have a scenario where user should be able to click on a link from this error message and navigate to a different page. 
I tried embedding  elements as it's display the 'Dismiss' hyperlink right next to these error message by default. However, this displays these tags as it is.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this capability is not supported for notification messages. They cannot display HTML content and will not honor anchor tags.